# What is the best way to insulate attic walls in a balloon frame house?

Tags: insulation, attic

We are insulating the attic in our 1900 house with a balloon frame. The attic had an old wooden floor, so we plan to go over that with either mineral wool or XPS. The floor boards run to the wall studs and the space between the studs is open. In some places, it goes all the way down. (See photo). We understand that in balloon framing these wall cavities need to breathe, so completely sealing them off seems like a bad idea. On the other hand, laying insulation that leaves these cavities wide open also seems less than ideal.

We have considered cutting mineral wool to go in between the wall studs. As the photo shows, these are pretty small sections of about 20x15 inches. Our thinking is mineral wool is vapor permeable, so we'd be allowing some air movement and evaporation but stopping any big drafts traveling up the wall cavities to the attic. Would this work?

[image: Attic Walls and Floors]

Answer (score 1):

Since you have cavities that are easily accessible in the picture, rent yourself a blowing wool machine from a local big box store. Shove the hose as far down as possible into the cavities and start filling from the bottom up. The blowing wool will be flying everywhere, you may be able to minimize the problem by placing fiberglass batts at the top of the cavity to help the leaks. Mark the hose with duct tape perhaps about 1 ft. from the end so that much will stay in the cavity. At least this is what I would while the stud bay tops are open and will readily receive insulation.

The blowing wool is completely breathable, as long as the wool is packed well in the cavity, it should not settle, which blowing wool is prone to do if it is not tight.

Now if you are wanting to have your attic become a conditioned space, or better yet "tempered" since there may be no ductwork servicing the space, the cheapest way is to place kraft faced fiberglass batts in the stud bays and roof rafters. The best way to insulate the attic is using a 1/2 pound spray in foam. It is really pricey, but its R value is much better than fiberglass, it is permeable too.

Comment: For the fiberglass batts, would the kraft paper be up toward the open attic space, or down toward the ceiling below?